# comm.bcast not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to test a simple mpi code on python with the following code :

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from mpi4py import MPI

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()

if rank == 0:
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    indices = [1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    indptr = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    #A=csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(4,4))                                                                                                              

data=comm.bcast(data, root=0)
indices=comm.bcast(indices, root=0)
indptr=comm.bcast(indptr, root=0)

print rank,data,indices,indptr
```

which returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    data=comm.bcast(data, root=0)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    data=comm.bcast(data, root=0)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    data=comm.bcast(data, root=0)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 3, 2, 1, 0] [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[10263,1],1]
  Exit code:    1
```

It seems like the error is due to me not using comm.bcast properly, but that is exactly how its used in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining `data` in the `if` block. What happens when the `if` block is `false`? the variable `data` is not defined.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from mpi4py import MPI

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()

data = []
indices = []
indptr = []

if rank == 0:
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    indices = [1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    indptr = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    #A=csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(4,4))                                                                                                              

data=comm.bcast(data, root=0)
indices=comm.bcast(indices, root=0)
indptr=comm.bcast(indptr, root=0)

print rank,data,indices,indptr
```

This should now work.

Comment: isn't comm.bcast supposed to send data,indices,indptr to all procs ?

Comment: your code works, but it doesn't do what i want, the print should atleast be outside the if block to check if all procs got received data,indices,indptr. And in general comm.bcast don't need to be in the if block since its supposed to broadcast from rank = 0 to all available procs

Comment: you could define the data, indices, indptr outside (above the if block) as an empty list.

Comment: that works!!! without actually putting comm.bcast and print inside the if block. seems like they should be initialised ....

Comment: not very pythonic .. can you edit your answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: You can (and IMHO should) initialize the variables with `None`.